# Sizing requirements for Oracle downstream mining database while using Oracle Golden gate Downstream Integrated Capture

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I just want to know role of oracle downstream mining database machine in OGG downstream integrated capture mode. To be specific, I want to know whether the mining db also stores data or it only process the archive logs received from source and forward processed data to target without storing?

For example, if I have 1000 tables having size of 15TB in source system and I just want to replicate one table having size 1MB to the target, whether all the 1000 table having size of 15TB need to exist in downstream mining db, or none of the 1000 tables need to be exists in downstream mining DB, or only the interested table having size 1MB need to be exists in downstream mining DB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lack of points adding comments here.

No need of source table(s) or data files on Log mining server.Only Redo or Archive logs are shipped/transported from source db to Log mining server.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification